# Why do some REST calls that are virtually identical to working ones fail?

Tags: c#, rest, castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have several Controllers/Repositories that expose a `GetByID(int someInt)` method. In most cases they work, but in a couple they fail with a `404 (not found)` error.

For example, here is the code from a test client that calls two REST methods:

```
    GetById("inventories");
    . . .
    GetById("sitemapping"); 

private void GetById(string typeName)
{
    // Had to add the "constant" (1) to prevent very bad things from happening (wherein the runtime has delusions of being a runaway train (DeserializeObject() call otherwise fails if only returning one "record"))
    string uri = string.Format("{0}/{1}/1", typeName, numericUpDownId.Value);
    Popul8TheGrid(uri);
}

private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();
    var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
}

private void Popul8TheGrid(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetRESTData(BASE_URI + uri);
    }
    catch (WebException webex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Eek, a mousey-pooh! ({0})", webex.Message));
    }
}
```

The Repository methods that are ultimately called are virtually identical:

Inventory (working):

```
private readonly List<Inventory> inventories = new List<Inventory>();
. . .

public Inventory GetById(int ID)
{
    return inventories.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == ID);
}
```

Inventory Model, wherein can be seen that "Id" is an int:

```
public class Inventory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string InventoryName { get; set; } 
. . .
}
```

Sitemapping (not working / not found (404):

```
private readonly List<SiteMapping> siteMappings = new List<SiteMapping>();
. . .
public SiteMapping GetById(int ID)
{
    return siteMappings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.site_no == ID);
}
```

SiteMapping Model, wherein can be seen that "site_no" is an int:

```
public class SiteMapping
{
    public int site_no { get; set; }
    public string location_num { get; set; }
}
```

Why would Inventories work and SiteMapping fail?

### UPDATE

For Keith:

URL (examples) are:

```
http://localhost:28642/api/sitemapping/3
```

-and:

```
http://localhost:28642/api/inventories/42
```

And I can add that first one directly in my browser, and it works fine: it returns the expected "record" as XML in Chrome. It's just from the code shown that calling it fails.

As to routing configuration, I'm using Castle Windsor, and code like this in RepositoriesInstaller:

```
Component.For<IInventoryRepository>().ImplementedBy<InventoryRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
. . .
Component.For<ISiteMappingRepository>().ImplementedBy<SiteMappingRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
```

But this is not a/the problem, as related method calls work fine (I should have mentioned this: I can call the other SiteMapping methods, namely Count and GetAll, and all is well - it's only the "GetByID()" that fails.

### UPDATE 2

Kiran, I'm not sure what you mean, but if you mean my Controllers' attribute routing, here they are:

Working (Inventory):

```
private readonly IInventoryRepository _inventoryRepository;

public InventoriesController(IInventoryRepository inventoryRepository)
{
    if (inventoryRepository == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("inventoryRepository");
    }
    _inventoryRepository = inventoryRepository;
}

[Route("api/Inventories/{ID:int}")] 
public Inventory GetInventoryById(int ID)
{
    return _inventoryRepository.GetById(ID);
}
```

Nonworking (as to the GetByID() method only) (SiteMapping):

```
public readonly ISiteMappingRepository _sitemappingsRepository;

public SiteMappingController(ISiteMappingRepository sitemappingsRepository)
{
    if (sitemappingsRepository == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("SiteMappingController");
    }
    _sitemappingsRepository = sitemappingsRepository;
}

[Route("api/SiteMapping/{ID:int}")]
public SiteMapping GetSiteMappingById(int ID)
{
    return _sitemappingsRepository.GetById(ID);
}
```

Comment: What are the urls that are used for the requests, and what is your MVC routing configuration code?

Comment: Can you share how your routes look like?

Comment: @KiranChalla: Updated again.

Comment: I was hoping to see the exact urls that are used to make the request. You can see it easily with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).

Comment: Fiddler doesn't work so good/easily with Chrome, and IE is, for some reason, brain-dead on my installation. The exact url is:
http://localhost:28642/api/sitemapping/3